# Why my WinSCP login success, but get a empty library?

Tags: java, server, winscp

I use WinSCP to log in my remote server.

[image]

I login in, but you see the server library is empty:

[image]

You see, the right is a empty library, why?
where is the folders?

Comment: have you tried use the username is root to login?

Comment: @aircraft Oh, thank you, I success.

Answer (score 0):

Check your account's permissions in the server.

Comment: how to check it? I only have this account in the server.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you login your remote server should use root account, it has the whole permission.